# One 1-1 relationship and two 1-n relationships in one model

Tags: c#, sql, entity, relationship

My WerehouseKey class:

```
public class WerehouseKey
{
    [Key]
    public int WhKeyID { get; set; }

    (...)

    public virtual KeyRent KeyRent { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Magazyn")]
    public int WhID { get; set; }
    public virtual Werehouse Werehouse { get; set; }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    (...)

    public virtual ICollection<KeyRent> RUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<KeyRent> GUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my KeyRent class:

```
public class KeyRent
{
    [Key]
    public int WhKeyID { get; set; }

    (...)

    public virtual WerehouseKey WerehouseKey { get; set; }

    public int RUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User RentingUser { get; set; }

    public int GUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User GivingUser { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have relationship between WerehouseKey and KeyRent in 1-1, it works perfectly, then I want to have two 1-n relationships in KeyRent between it and User. Basicly one user rents key and one user gives key, they both can have many keys rent/given. I have my own OnModelCreating function:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<KeyRent>()
            .HasKey(e => e.WhKeyID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WerehouseKey>()
                    .HasOptional(s => s.KeyRent)
                    .WithRequired(ad => ad.WerehouseKey);

        modelBuilder.Entity<KeyRent>()
                .HasRequired<User>(s => s.RentingUser)
                .WithMany(s => s.RUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.RUserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<KeyRent>()
                .HasRequired<User>(s => s.GivingUser)
                .WithMany(s => s.GUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.GUserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany<KeyRent>(s => s.GUsers)
                .WithOptional(s => s.GivingUser)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.GUserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany<KeyRent>(s => s.RUsers)
                .WithOptional(s => s.RentingUser)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.RUserID);
    }
```

The thing is that when I want to add-migration it show me this error

> "The navigation property 'GivingUser' declared on type 'WerehouseProject.Models.KeyRent' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities."

Can someone show me what is wrong here and how it can be fixed?